# Does NFQUEUE handles tcp reassembly?

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel, netfilter

I am using NFQUEUE for getting packets into my user-space code. I am worried about TCP segments. I am doing some pattern matching into my user-space code.

Does NFQUEUE take care of TCP segments? And what about IP fragments??

If not, then any useful solutions? or I have to write a code to cache packet data & do re-assembly?

Comment: I google it out. And I tried to broadcast segmented packets. NFQUEUE is not managing that. I have to do by my own.

Comment: Now what about IP fragments?? And suggest me good implementation for TCP re-assembly.